# Scaling Object in responsive design

Tags: html, css

what I am trying to accomplish is to make my object scale with my browser window. As I increase the browser the object just moves directly up instead of just staying in the same position and scaling with the browser. The video that I have the object on scales just fine it's the object on top that I am having problems with. If anyone has any suggestions that would really help. Thank you!

Here is a JsFiddle but I'm not sure how helpful it'll be.

https://jsfiddle.net/tad1jcxt/

HTML:

```
<figure class="stayssame">
<video controls loop poster="placeholder.png" autoplay>
<source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 <!-- <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">-->
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<h1 id="headline">Intermediate Web Design:
<br>
Fun, Insightful, Experience
</h1>
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="comweb2.svg" ></object>
</figure>
```

CSS:

```
object{
top:8.5%;   
left:32%;
height: 100px;
width:200px;
}

#headline{
text-align: center;
position: absolute;

top:10%;
left:35%;
color:#00E3FF;
line-height:20px;
font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
word-spacing: 1px;
font-size:12px;

}
```

Comment: Please create a snippet instead of just posting code.

Comment: @connexo I added a JsFiddle is that what you wanted?

Comment: Please make yourself familiar with the options the SO text editor grants.

Comment: @connexo I'm fairly new to stackoverflow so that doesn't work?

Comment: @Cakers - in the SO editor there is an option to make a "snippet", which is much like a fiddle but appears in your question instead of being on a different site. On the editor toolbar it looks like a page with `<>` brackets on it, and has a shortcut key `Ctrl+M`

Comment: @StephenP Thank you so much for explaining this!

Answer (score 1):

The desired screen position of your <object> (containing a graphic) is 8.5% of the screen height from the top, and 32% of the screen width from the left hand side.  However, the `top` and `left` CSS properties only apply to absolutely positioned elements; e.g., `position: fixed` or `position: absolute`.  Therefore, simply add `position: absolute` to  your CSS properties for the <object> and you're good to go.

```
     object{
        position: absolute;
        top:8.5%;
        left:32%;
        height: 100px;
        width:200px;
    }
```

I also strongly recommend that you not change the global definition of an <object> element in this case because it seems very specific to this instance.  It is best to give your <object> an ID attribute and then use that to give it the CSS properties desired:

```
<style>
    #logo{
        position: absolute;
        top:8.5%;
        left:32%;
        height: 100px;
        width:200px;
    }
</style>
<object id="logo" type="image/svg+xml" data="comweb2.svg" ></object>
```

---

*For reference:*

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top